# Trying to make a jquery widget responsive

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

Hi I am trying to get this jquery widget to go responsive. Iv tried replacing widths with percentages. I found it originally on http://jqueryglobe.com/article/feature_list/ but the site as since been removed, i have it on my own site here http://www.piercemcgeough.co.uk/sidetabs/

The problem seems to be the tab because it is a set image with a width and height.

Any help please guys. Thanks you

Comment: you can also scale images to 100% of their parent. Of course some clipping may occur (the parent's overflow should be hidden with a fixed height).

Comment: question doesn't include any specific details of problems you are having or criteria on what `responsive` means with regard to your widget and it's components

Answer (score 0):

Could be a challenge to simply scale everything because as the images get smaller, their height isn't going to match what's required to display the 3 links on the left.

The current structure is basically:

```
#tabs    #output  .right
```

What about using @media requests and start modifying this as the viewpoint gets smaller?

For tablets

```
#tabs  #output  
.right
```

For smartphones

```
#tabs  
#output  
.right
```

The CSS would loosely be

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
/* for tablets, drop right div below left div */

.left, .right{
width:100%;
}

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

/* below tablets stack tabs, output and right divs vertically */

.left #tabs, .left #output, .right{
width:100%;
}

Also at the moment the width of div#feature_list is hardwired to 750px. Probably good to change this to a percentage (possibly 100%).

You may also need to force the images in the output div to scale with something like

```
ul#output li img{ 
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

For sure there will be more fine tuning required than this, though I think the important thing is that if you want to make this both responsive and usable, you will need to start thinking about changing its layout as the viewpoint changes. You won't simply be able to scale everything.

Good luck, it's an interesting time for web design!